# How to find vertices that are within polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a network of edges and nodes located within 3 zones, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to know, for each node, which zone it belongs to.
Is there a way to extract the information?

So that I have a column in the attributes of the vertices with either Zone_1, Zone_2 or Zone_3?
(In reality I have a bigger network with many zones, and would like a fast way to recover this information for `each node`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply an **Intersection** (*Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Intersection...*) using your point data as *Input layer* and the zonal polygons as *Overlay layer*. This will add the intersected polygon's attributes to each point (you can also also select specific attributes to keep).

Answer (score 0):

if you doesn't want create a new layer using Intersection tool, you can:

1. create a new field in your point layer and call it as
   'fk_id_polygon'
2. writing this formula by field calculator

   aggregate(

   layer:='layer_name_polygon',
   aggregate:='max',
   expression:= "id_polygon",
   filter:= within(geometry(@parent),$geometry)
   )

the formula retrieve the field "id_polygon" from polygon table and write the value in  attribute cell, for only point within polygons.

"id_polygon" field has to be a unique value that identify each single polygon.

After that you can do Join between 'fk_polygon_id' and 'id_polygon'

or instead of use 'id_polygon' you can use 'name' so to associate Zone name directly at your points